# How can I handle collisions in unity without a rigidbody?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I want to pretend that objects go trough each other. I know that these things are normaly handled by the rigidbody. But I dont want to use a rigidbody because of performance reasons. So how should I do that?  Should I use something like that  https://github.com/tejas123/collision-detection-without-rigid-body-in-unity?  Or is there a better way to do it. Also what uses the least performance for a mobile phone? For the movement of the objects I use Vector3.translate.  Should I use something other?  Any help would be great

Comment: First, StackOverflow is not for opinion based questions, it is for answering specific question. Second how many rigidbodies do you have? Unity can handle several thousands. There are many methods, raycasting, point detection. The majority of Unity's tools will work just fine.

Comment: you're actually in the right direction, just to not let you in the dark, most games actually do their own collision detection with RAYCASTS not just for performance, but for more control on how the physics itself should behave, you want to learn about raycasts.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is a performance issue, any other solution will cost high for you. but if you want to make a custom script, you can use Raycast or [Collision contact point](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html), and then stop your object's movement to simulate hit effect.